# Google Analytics opt-in keeps opt-out

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

My code does not allow me to opt-in back to Google Analytics. What would be the way to set again the Google Analytics cookie to opt-in or how to remove the state of opt-out to be again opt-in?

**The Google Analytics debugger**

```
Initializing Google Analytics.
Running command: ga("create", "UA-XXXXXXX-2", "electronics.semaf.at")
Creating new tracker: t0
Aborting cookie write: User has opted out of tracking.
Aborting cookie write: User has opted out of tracking.
Running command: ga("set", "anonymizeIp", true)
Running command: ga("set", "forceSSL", true)
Running command: ga("send", "pageview")
User has opted out of tracking. Aborting hit.
Registered new plugin: ga(provide, "render", Function)
```

**My Javascript Code to opt-in and opt-out:**

```
<script>
      var gaProperty = 'UA-XXXXXXX-2';
      var disableStr = 'ga-disable-' + gaProperty;
      if (document.cookie.indexOf(disableStr + '=true') > -1) {
        window[disableStr] = true;
      }
      // Opt-out function
      function gaOptout() {
        document.cookie = disableStr + '=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC; path=/';
        window[disableStr] = true;
        location.reload(true);
      }
      // Opt-in function
      function gaOptin() {
        document.cookie = disableStr + '=false; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC; path=/';
        window[disableStr] = false;
        location.reload(true);
      }
</script>
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-2', 'auto');
    ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
    ga('set', 'forceSSL', true);
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

**This it the part to opt-in or opt-out**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(window[disableStr] == true) {
    document.getElementById("google_analytics").innerHTML = 'You are opt-out from Google Analytics. <a href="javascript:gaOptin()">Opt-in</a>';}
  else {
    document.getElementById("google_analytics").innerHTML = 'This page is using <a href="http://analytics.google.com/">Google Analytics</a>. <a href="javascript:gaOptout()">Opt-out</a>';
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Opt-in function
  function gaOptin() {
    document.cookie = disableStr + '=false; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;';
    window[disableStr] = false;
    location.reload(true);
  }
```

If you need more Information about deleting cookies read this:
[w3schools Cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)